# Half Sibling Centimorgans

Tags: research-methods

I recently had contact with a person who was matched as a possible first cousin on Ancestry.  We only share 753 Centimorgans and we originally thought we may be half siblings/ I am adopted and she saw matches on both her Father’s Mother and Father’s side. I don’t think we can be half siblings with that low number.  Any ideas of a possible connection?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Maybe cousins? Check the chart and see what relationships fit.